# Want to convert nested for loop into recursive,

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, nested-loops

```
    for (const item in sourceJson) {
          for (const targ_item in targetJson) {
            if(targ_item === item && targ_item !== 'master' && item !== 'master'){ 
              
    
              let tarJson = targetJson[item]['master'];
              let serJson = sourceJson[item]['master'];
    
              let distinctKyaVal = {};
              for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(tarJson)) {
                if (!(key in serJson)) {
                  distinctKyaVal[key] = tarJson[key];
                }
              }
              sourceJson[item]['master'] = {...sourceJson[item]['master'], ...distinctKyaVal};
              targetJson[item] = sourceJson[item];
            }
          }
        }
    return targetJson;



targetJson = {
    "idp-cms-feed": {
        "feedID": "09adfe0a-aba2-3d3b-a826-5a1c9d26670e",
        "feedTimeStamp": "2021-03-25T15:45:58.083-0500",
        "myorders": {
            "analytics": {
                "lineOfBusiness": "general"
            },
            "configuration": {
                "enablePersonalization": true
            },
            "seo": {
                "disableBreadCrumbs": false,
                "twittercard": "summary",
                "metaRobots": "INDEX,FOLLOW"
            },
            "pageinfo": {
                "lineOfBusiness": "general",
                "releaseName": "2103d,2103c,2103b,2101b",
                "releasePath": "/idpassets/fragment/services"
            },
            "ogtype": "website",
            "disableBreadcrumb": "false",
            "lob": "general",
            "breadcrumbStatus": "auto",
            "contentFragments": {
                "orderInfo": {
                    "master": {
                        "title": "Order details",
                        "orderNumber": "Order #",
                        "orderDate": "Ordered:",
                        "ceaseTitle": "Cancellation info",
                        "returnToOrderSummaryLinkLabel": "Return to Order summary",
                        "shippingAddressLabel": "Shipping address:",
                        "variationID": "25c344dd-145b-3bed-9d06-6696c9563377"
                    }
                },
                "equipment": {
                    "master": {
                        "accordianTitle": "Equipment",
                        "IHXAccordianTitle": "Delivery and setup info",
                        "attTvEquipmentTitle": "AT&T TV equipment",
                        "attTvNowEquipmentTitle": "AT&T TV NOW equipment",
                        "singleStreamingDevice": "device",
                        "multiStreamingDevice": "devices",
                        "estimatedShipDateLabel": "Expected to ship:",
                        "shippedOnDateLabel": "Shipped on:",
                        "estimatedDeliveryDateLabel": "Expected to deliver:",
                        "deliveredOnDateLabel": "Delivered on:",
                        "trackingLabel": "tracking #:",
                        "addressLabel": "Address:",
                        "variationID": "36652467-454d-3184-b961-e0dad29cd483"
                    }
                },
                "carrierTracker": {
                    "master": {
                        "shipmentInfoLabel": "SHIPMENT INFO",
                        "returnShippingStatusLabel": "Return shipping status:",
                        "deliveredStatus": "Delivered",
                        "outForDeliveryStatus": "Out for delivery",
                        "inTransitStatus": "In transit",
                        "inTransitText": "Last scan at",
                        "carrierPickedUpStatus": "Carrier picked up",
                        "disclaimerText": "*Local time shown",
                        "variationID": "f5d74d7a-2166-3802-9a6a-a5e63e9ba49c",
                        "carrierTrackerErrorLabel": "Oops! We had a system glitch and can’t show your shipping info. Try refreshing your screen. If that doesn’t work, give it some time and try again later."
                    }
                },
                "tradeIn": {
                    "master": {
                        "tradeInAlert": "We see your order includes a trade-in. Be sure to send us your used device within 30 days after you activate your new one. Look for the  <a target = '_self' role = \"link\" aria-label=\\\"Trade in section\\\"  href = '#TradeIn'> trade-in info</a> for more details.",
                        "tradeInHeader": "Trade in",
                        "tradeInCountText": "Trade-in devices:",
                        "attTradeInText": "AT&T TRADE-IN",
                        "tradeInKitText": "<b>Trade-in kit</b>",
                        "tradeInProcessText": "Have questions about the trade-in process?",
                        "tradeInLink": "https://tradein.att.com/trade-in-status",
                        "tradeInAnswersText": "Get answers",
                        "nextStepsLabel": "Next steps",
                        "nextStepsList": [
                            "Sign up for an eligible AT&T unlimited plan to qualify for the promo.",
                            "Wait for your shipping kit to arrive in 5 - 7 days. It ships separately from your new device.",
                            "Review and complete the tasks outlined in the Pre-shipping checklist.",
                            "Use the trade-in shipping kit to send us your old device."
                        ],
                        "preShippingLabel": "Pre-shipping checklist",
                        "preShippingList": [
                            "Back up or transfer personal info to a different device.",
                            "Turn off activation locks.",
                            "Remove SIM and memory cards.",
                            "Perform factory reset to delete personal info from device."
                        ],
                        "importantDetailsLabel": "Important details",
                        "importantDetailsList": [
                            "Send us your old device within 30 days from activating your new device.",
                            "Don’t use the return labels included with your new device.",
                            "Each trade-in device must be mailed in its own shipping kit.",
                            "The trade-in device can’t be returned to you.",
                            "Any remaining data on your old device isn't recoverable."
                        ],
                        "seeDetailsLinkLabel": "See Details",
                        "seeDetailsLink": "https://tradein.att.com/offer-details",
                        "startedLabel": "Started",
                        "reaturnedLabel": "In transit",
                        "pendingLabel": "Pending",
                        "waitingLabel": "Waiting",
                        "receivedLabel": "Received",
                        "completedLabel": "Completed",
                        "packageReceivedLabel": "Package received",
                        "canceledLabel": "Canceled",
                        "tradeInItemName": "Package for [[itemName]]",
                        "tradeInKitName": "Your trade-in: [[itemName]]",
                        "invoiceLabel": "Confirmation #:",
                        "tradeInPromoText": "Trade-in promo:",
                        "tradeInEstimatedLabelText": "Estimated trade-in value:",
                        "tradeInEstimatedValueDisclaimerText": "*You’ll receive the trade-in value as an AT&T promotional card. Use the card to buy products at any AT&T-owned store or on att.com. You can also use it to pay your AT&T wireless bill.",
                        "finalTradeinOfferValueText": "Final trade-in offer value:",
                        "monthlyBillCreditText": "Monthly bill credit:",
                        "billCreditStartDateText": "Bill credit start date:",
                        "tradeInPromoValueText": "Up to $[[promoValue]] off with qualifying trade-in*",
                        "tradeInDisclaimerText": "*We apply monthly credits over the term of the installment plan. Credits start within three bill periods. Depending upon your trade-in device, you may receive an AT&T Promotion Card or one-time credit instead.",
                        "tradeInStartedInstructionsText": "*We apply monthly credits over the term of the installment plan. Credits start within three bill periods. Depending upon your trade-in device, you may receive an AT&T Promotion Card or one-time credit instead.",
                        "tradeInStartedInstructionsText1": "Need to get a replacement trade-in kit or print your labels? Go to ",
                        "tradeInInstructionsLabel": "Trade-in instructions",
                        "tradeInStartedInstructionsText2": "Steps to trade in your device",
                        "tradeInStartedBoxText": "1. Get your return label",
                        "tradeInStartedBoxDesc": "You’ll get your return shipping label in one of three ways: In the box your new device came in, in a trade-in kit we send you, or in an email we send you. If you get an email, look for a link to print a return label.",
                        "tradeInStartedChecklistText": "2. Prep your device for shipment",
                        "tradeInStartedChecklistDesc": "For the best experience, be sure to get your trade-in device ready to send it to us.",
                        "learnHowLinkLabel": "Learn how",
                        "tradeInStartedPersonalDeliveryText": "3. Drop off your package",
                        "tradeInStartedPersonalDeliveryDesc": "Use the label you received to drop your device off at the post office. If you printed the label from an email we sent, you'll drop it off at a UPS location instead.",
                        "tradeInDetailsLabel": "More details",
                        "tradeInDetailsStartedInstructionsText3": "How to prep your trade-in device",
                        "tradeInDetailsStartedInstructionsText3List": [
                            "Back up or transfer personal info to a different device.",
                            "Turn off activation locks (like Find My iPhone or Find My Device).",
                            "Remove SIM and memory cards.",
                            "Perform a factory reset to delete personal info from the device."
                        ],
                        "tradeInDetailsStartedInstructionsText4": "Important info",
                        "tradeInDetailsStartedInstructionsText4List": [
                            "Make sure to send in your used device within 30 days from activating your new one.",
                            "Use the shipping label we provided you."
                        ],
                        "tradeInDetailsStartedInstructionsText5": "<b>Good to know:</b><br>The trade-in device can’t be returned to you. Plus, any data that's still on your used device isn't recoverable.<br>",
                        "tradeInDetailsCompletedInstructionsText1List": [
                            "We inspected your trade-in device and determined it qualifies for $[[tradeinValue]] in promo credits.",
                            "You’ll start seeing the monthly promo credits on your bill within three bill periods. The credits will apply over the term of the installment plan. [[viewBill]]",
                            "Have questions? Call us at 800.331.0500."
                        ],
                        "viewYourBillLable": "View your bill",
                        "viewYourBillLink": "https://www.att.com/acctmgmt/billandpay",
                        "shipmentInfoLabel": "Shipment info",
                        "returnedOnLabel": "Returned on:",
                        "shippedOnLabel": "Shipped on:",
                        "tradeInReturnedReceivedInstruText1": "Keep in mind, the trade-in device can’t be returned to you.",
                        "tradeInReturnedReceivedInstruText2": "Have questions about the trade-in process? Go to",
                        "receivedOnLabel": "Received on:",
                        "tradeInLinkLabel": "tradein.att.com/trade-in-status",
                        "tradeInOfferLabel": "Get more trade-in details",
                        "seeTradeInDetailsLinkLabel": "See trade-in details",
                        "devicePhoneLabel": "Number associated with the trade-in:",
                        "tradeInStatusLabel": "Trade-in status:",
                        "tradeInHeaderLabel": "Test",
                        "variationID": "c254f71f-1793-38dd-a17f-0e544da0f303",
                        "instructionsTradeInLinkLabel": "tradein.att.com",
                        "instructionsTradeInLink": "https://tradein.att.com"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "feedVersion": "210324135254"
    }
}

sourceJson ={
    "orderInfo": {
        "master": {
            "title": "Order details",
            "orderNumber": "Order #",
            "orderDate": "Ordered:",
            "ceaseTitle": "Cancellation info",
            "returnToOrderSummaryLinkLabel": "Return to Order summary",
            "shippingAddressLabel": "Shipping address:",
            "serviceAddressLabel": "Service address is",
            "onPageLoadSpinnerContent": "Hang on…we’re getting your order info",
            "billingAddressLabel": "Billing address:",
            "snagTitle": "Oops! We hit a snag.",
            "eSimShippingLabel": "Ship to:",
            "tvCashCarryOrderLabel": "Ordered on:",
            "chckTitle": "Congrats on your purchase!",
            "variationID": "25c344dd-145b-3bed-9d06-6696c9563377"
        }
    }
}
```

here I am two nested objects(targetJson, sourceJson), basically what I want to do is to compare these two objects recursively and if key matched then copy the key value from sourceJson to targetJson, and suppose if there is a new key which is available in targetJson nested object but not in sourceJson then also keep that key-value object in targetJson.
thnx in advanced.

Comment: Can you put examples of sourceJson and targetJson?

Comment: @JairLopezGutierrez added json data, pls check

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is only composed from primitive value, plain object or array, here is a solution for a recursive "copyTo" function:

```js
const copyTo = (source, destination) => {
    for (const key in source) {
        const sourceValue = source[key]
        const isObject = !!sourceValue && typeof sourceValue === 'object'
        if (isObject) {
            const destinatonHasEntry = key in destination
  
            if (destinatonHasEntry === false) {
                // create the entry (plain object or array)
                destination[key] = Array.isArray(sourceValue) ? [] : {}
            }
  
            copyTo(sourceValue, destination[key])
        } else {
            // sourceValue is a primitive value
            destination[key] = sourceValue
        }
    }
}

const obj1 = { foo: 2, bar: { qux: 2 }, arr: [10,,30], x: 'X', y:['a', { b:'B' }] }
const obj2 = { foo: 0, bar: { qux: 0 }, arr: [1, 2, 3] }

copyTo(obj1, obj2)

console.log(obj2)
```

Comment: hi, first of all thnx for the help. pls check attached fiddle link. what i need is, source orderInfo should be copy in idp-cms-feed->myorders->contentFragments->orderInfo and also keep distinct key value of ' idp-cms-feed->myorders->contentFragments->orderInfo' in it
https://jsfiddle.net/ajaysingh13500/adpwym2z/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can write `copy` using [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. if `src` is not an object, return `src` unmodified
2. (inductive) `src` is an object. For each entry `k,v` compute the sub-problem and assign to `k` in result `r`.

```js
const copy = (src = {}, dst = {}) =>
  src?.constructor !== Object
    ? src
    : Object
        .entries(src)
        .reduce
          ( (r, [k, v]) =>
              ({ ...r, [k]: copy(v, dst?.[k]) })
          , dst
          )
          
const source =
  { a: 1, b: { c: 1, d: { e: 1, g: 1 } }, z: 1 }
  
const target =
  { a: 0, b: { c: 0, d: { e: 0, f: 0 } } }
  
console.log("result", JSON.stringify(copy(source, target)))
console.log("source", JSON.stringify(source))
console.log("target", JSON.stringify(target))
```

```js
result {"a":1,"b":{"c":1,"d":{"e":1,"f":0,"g":1}},"z":1}
source {"a":1,"b":{"c":1,"d":{"e":1,"g":1}},"z":1}
target {"a":0,"b":{"c":0,"d":{"e":0,"f":0}}}
```

The input source and target objects are *not* modified as part of the `copy` operation. Instead a *new* object is created as a result. Above we use a pure functional expression. We can trade that for some imperative style syntax if that is more comfortable/familiar for you. Both examples produce the same output -

```js
function copy (src = {}, dst = {}) {
  if (src?.constructor !== Object)
    return src
  else
    return Object
      .entries(src)
      .reduce
        ( (r, [k, v]) =>
            ({ ...r, [k]: copy(v, dst?.[k]) })
        , dst
        )
}
          
const source =
  { a: 1, b: { c: 1, d: { e: 1, g: 1 } }, z: 1 }
  
const target =
  { a: 0, b: { c: 0, d: { e: 0, f: 0 } } }
  
console.log("result", JSON.stringify(copy(source, target)))
console.log("source", JSON.stringify(source))
console.log("target", JSON.stringify(target))
```

```js
result {"a":1,"b":{"c":1,"d":{"e":1,"f":0,"g":1}},"z":1}
source {"a":1,"b":{"c":1,"d":{"e":1,"g":1}},"z":1}
target {"a":0,"b":{"c":0,"d":{"e":0,"f":0}}}
```

If your data were significantly large, @ScottSauyet points out a problem that can be easily remedied by avoiding unnecessary creation of intermediate data -

```js
const copy = (src = {}, dst = {}) =>
  src?.constructor !== Object
    ? src
    : Object
        .entries(src)
        .reduce
          ( (r, [k, v]) =>
            ( r[k] = copy(v, dst?.[k])
            , r
            )
          , { ...dst }
          )
          
const source =
  { a: 1, b: { c: 1, d: { e: 1, g: 1 } }, z: 1 }
  
const target =
  { a: 0, b: { c: 0, d: { e: 0, f: 0 } } }
  
console.log("result", JSON.stringify(copy(source, target)))
console.log("source", JSON.stringify(source))
console.log("target", JSON.stringify(target))
```

```js
result {"a":1,"b":{"c":1,"d":{"e":1,"f":0,"g":1}},"z":1}
source {"a":1,"b":{"c":1,"d":{"e":1,"g":1}},"z":1}
target {"a":0,"b":{"c":0,"d":{"e":0,"f":0}}}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting the potential [performance problem](https://www.richsnapp.com/blog/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) of `reduce-{....spread}`.  I don't usually let it stop me unless it actually proves to be a problem, but there is a real threat.

Comment: thanks for the comment Scott, i provided a third example which uses shallow copy and unobservable mutation in the `reduce` loop

Comment: I usually choose ` ... => ((a[k] = v, a)`.  That's mostly because I think of `Object .assign` as creating new objects, which in turn is mostly because I always use it defensively with an initial empty object.  Of course even more, I tend to just use the `reduce-{...spread}` pattern unless I've demonstrated it to be an actual bottleneck in my code.  Usually I'm fine with that, but I'm starting to think that this might be one of those places to do a defensive optimization.

Comment: thanks, i'll take it! it avoids another intermediate object of `{ [k]: ... }` as well :D i tend to think of `Object.assgin` as a function form of its assignment syntax soup counterpart, `t[k] = v`

Answer (score 0):

Editing @JosephMerdrignac answer:

```
const copyTo = (destination) => {
        for (const key in destination) {
          console.log("key: ", key);
            const destinationValue = destination[key];
            const isObject = !!destinationValue && typeof destinationValue === 'object';
            if (isObject) {
                if("orderInfo" in destination[key]){
                  console.log("******inside exist orderInfo");
                  destination[key] = {
                    ...destination[key],
                    orderInfo: sourceJson["orderInfo"]
                  }
                }

                copyTo(destination[key]);
            }
        }
    }

    copyTo(targetJson)

    console.log(targetJson)
```